# How to generate a www LetsEncrypt certificate using laravel forge?

Tags: laravel, laravel-forge

I provisioned a server using forge and set the domain to `blog.example.com`. And I generate a LetsEncrypt certificate for that server and set the site to run on http2. It was perfectly fine.

However, I need to make the server accessible via `www.blog.example.com` now. So I set a CNAME record to route `www.blog` to `blog.example.com`. But I got an error `This site can’t provide a secure connection` when I try to access the site via `www.blog.example.com`. So I try to generate a new certificate for `www.blog.example.com` but forge reply `First domain does not match root domain on site`.

How can I solve the problem?

Thank you.

Comment: What command are you running to generate a new cert?

Comment: It's not a command. Laravel forge has a function that can generate and install a new cert by just a few clicks.

Comment: given that blog is already a subdomain, why do you want to have www in there too?

Comment: For SEO purpose only, I saw many SEO checkers said I need to make www.blog accessible for better ranking

Comment: I'm not an SEO expert, but I feel that is mainly for example.com vs www.example.com? You could always submit a ticket with forge to ask them how to set it up like you want